# How do I access a parent object's name in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a universal function that can log some useful data in several different objects, but I don't want to have to pass a parameter that is unique to each object.  Ideally, the initial name of the object, like LaunchRequestHandler would be a perfectly sufficient bit of data to use.  How can I access this object's name?

```
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        //I want to be able to know the name of the outer parent here.
        //In this case, I would expect to retrieve 'LaunchRequestHandler'
        logCanHandle(handlerInput);
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. The variable containing the object is not the object, whatever the variable's name is, it has nothing to do with the object it contains. If you wrote `const x = LaunchRequestHandler; x.canHandle()...`, what would you log, `x` or `LaunchRequestHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what are you trying to do but maybe you can do something with ES6 classes, like so:

```
class LaunchRequestHandler {
    canHandle() {
        console.log(this.constructor.name);
    }
};

const x = new LaunchRequestHandler();
x.canHandle(); // outputs 'LaunchRequestHandler'
```